# dplyr mutate/transmute: drop only the columns used in the formula

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose my data frame has columns A, B, C, D, E.

I want to produce a data frame with columns A, B, C, X, where X = D * E.

Obviously I can use `%>% mutate(X = D * E) %>% select (-D, -E)`, but for more elaborate situations, is there a way to do it in a single command?  Like `transmute()`, but only discarding the columns that were mentioned.

Silly, but I keep wishing for this bit of conciseness.

Comment: `transmute` returns only those collumns that are passed into.  So, you need `df %>% transmute(A, B, C, X = D*E)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking to combine the two operations, you can use `NULL` in `mutate` to specify which columns should be dropped:

```
df %>% mutate( X=D*E, D=NULL, E=NULL )
```

Unfortunately, you still have to mention each variable twice, so perhaps it's only marginally more concise.

**UPDATE:** So, I really like this question because it essentially requests a mutator that has some features of both `mutate` and `transmute`. Such a mutator will need to parse the provided expression(s) to identify which symbols are being used by the computation and then remove those symbols from the result.

To implement such a mutator, we will need some tools. First, let's define a function that retrieves an expression's [abstract syntax tree (AST)](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html#abstract-syntax-trees).

```
library( tidyverse )

## Recursively constructs the abstract syntax tree (AST) of the provided expression
getAST <- function( ee ) { as.list(ee) %>% map_if(is.call, getAST) }
```

Here's an example of `getAST` in action:

```
z <- quote( a*log10(x)+b )   ## Captures the expression a*log10(x)+b
getAST( z ) %>% str
# List of 3
#  $ : symbol +
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ : symbol *
#   ..$ : symbol a
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ : symbol log10
#   .. ..$ : symbol x
#  $ : symbol b
```

Retrieving the list of symbols used by an expression requires nothing more than flattening and deparsing this tree.

```
## Retrieves all symbols (as strings) used in a given expression
getSyms <- function( ee ) { getAST(ee) %>% unlist %>% map_chr(deparse) }
getSyms(z)
# [1] "+"     "*"     "a"     "log10" "x"     "b"
```

We are now ready to implement our new mutator that computes new columns (similar to `mutate`) and removes variables used in the computation (similar to `transmute`):

```
## A new mutator that removes all variables used by the computations
transmutate <- function( .data, ... )
{
    ## Capture the provided expressions and retrieve their symbols
    vSyms <- enquos(...) %>% map( ~getSyms(get_expr(.x)) )

    ## Identify symbols that are in common with the provided dataset
    ## These columns are to be removed
    vToRemove <- intersect( colnames(.data), unlist(vSyms) )

    ## Pass on the expressions to mutate to do the work
    ## Remove the identified columns from the result
    mutate( .data, ... ) %>% select( -one_of(vToRemove) )
}
```

Let's take the new function out for a spin:

```
## Expected output should include new columns X, Y
##    removed columns vs, drat, wt, mpg, and cyl
##    and everything else the same
## (Note that in the classical tidyverse spirit, rownames are not preserved)
transmutate( mtcars, X = ifelse( vs, drat, wt ), Y = mpg*cyl )
#     disp  hp  qsec am gear carb     X     Y
# 1  160.0 110 16.46  1    4    4 2.620 126.0
# 2  160.0 110 17.02  1    4    4 2.875 126.0
# 3  108.0  93 18.61  1    4    1 3.850  91.2
# 4  258.0 110 19.44  0    3    1 3.080 128.4
# ...
```

Comment: I didn't know about `D=NULL` -- pretty cool.  `transmutate()` definitely does what I asked for, and it's interesting to see between your answer and @akrun's that it really wasn't super-easy.  I'm tempted to think your solution worth submitting in a pull request to dplyr!

Comment: @DavidKaufman: You might be interested to know that I proposed `transmutate()` as a new feature for `dplyr`. Feel free to contribute to the discussion of its behavior: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3721

Answer (score 10):

We need to specify the columns of interest in `transmute` as it will returns only those columns that are passed into

```
df %>% 
    transmute(A, B, C, X = D*E)
```

---

If there are many columns, then one option to not type it one-by-one would be to convert it to symbol and then do the evaluation (`!!!`)

```
df %>% 
  transmute(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[1:3]), X = D*E)
```

Or if we don't know the index of the columns of interest but only the names of columns to remove

```
df %>% 
    transmute(!!! rlang::syms(setdiff(names(.), c('D', 'E'))), X = D*E)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 5*10, replace = TRUE), 
          ncol = 5, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:5])))
```

Comment: Interesting -- you point to things I should learn how to use.  I can't accept the answer as being in the spirit of the question, though, because it still requires specifying D and E twice.

Answer (score 3):

There are now an experimental method added to mutate which allows you to do this in one operation:

```
df %>% mutate(X = D * E, .keep = "unused")
```

It is also possible to specify where the new variables goes between the others. See https://rdrr.io/github/tidyverse/dplyr/man/mutate.html

Comment: this ".keep" argument is not working for me.. it simply creates a new variable filled with the character string "unused". Any idea why the function is recognizing this as a new variable, rather than an input to the function?

Comment: Can you clarify? This should still works exactly as intended. Do you have the latest version of dplyr? Did you remember the dot before the variable name? Try running this code, it should remove the mentioned variables: library(dplyr);
mutate(mtcars, X = mpg * cyl, .keep = "unused")